# Posting a json data in url -- Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have JSON data stored in a variable in `[{"totalspend": 3240.650785131, "dailybudget": 50.0}]` format.

I am trying to post this JSON data to a url using:

```
import requests
r = requests.post("myurl", myjson)
```

but I am not able to see the result on my url after executing the code.

Comment: What, does it contain a literal Python list? What does `print(repr(myjson))` show (please include the quotes that produces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server most likely expects the `Content-Type: application/json` header to be set:

```
r = requests.post("myurl", data=myjson, 
                  headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Do make sure that `myjson` is an actual JSON *string* and not a Python list.

If you are using `requests` version 2.4.2 or newer, you can leave the encoding of the JSON data entirely to the library; it'll set the correct Content-Type header for you automatically. You'd pass in the *Python object* (not a JSON string) to the `json` keyword argument:

```
 r = requests.post("myurl", data=myobject)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set headers first : 
Try :

```
import json
import requests
payload = {"totalspend": 3240.650785131, "dailybudget": 50.0}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```